# Keeping existing 301 redirects along with wildcard redirection

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have manually redirected some URLs from domainA to domainB like this

```
Redirect /abc123 https://domainB.com/abc/?page_url=12
```

If any user enters **domainA/abc123**, they ll land on **domainB.com/abc/?page_url=12** 
Now, I want to implement a wildcard redirect like this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !domainB.in$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domainB.in/something/?page_url=1&eid=$1 [L,R=301]
```

where user can add any string after domainA.com/STRING and that will be passed to domainB.com/something/?eid=STRING

How can I keep the existing manual redirects along with the wildcard redirect without conflict? If writing if-else condition in htaccess is possible, how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

`Redirect` is a mod_alias directive and `RewriteRule` is a mod_rewrite directive. Different Apache modules run independently and at different times during the request. mod_rewrite will run first, despite the apparent order of directives in the config file. You should avoid mixing redirects from both modules in the same config file to avoid such conflicts.

Convert your existing `Redirect` directives to use mod_rewrite instead and make sure the most specific redirects are first.

For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Specific redirects
RewriteRule ^abc123$ https://domainB.com/abc/?page_url=12 [R=302,L]

# General redirect
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !domainB\.in [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://domainB.in/something/?page_url=1&eid=$1 [R=301,L]
```

Note that the `Redirect` directive you posted, that did not explicitly state the status code, would have defaulted to a 302 (temporary) redirect.

However, it is always preferable to test with 302 (temporary) redirects to avoid caching issues.